# Adding views to Toolbar removes the programatically set title when using the CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

When I add views to the Toolbar the programatically added title I added using setTitle() disappears.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorAccent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:expandedTitleMarginTop="32dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"


                >


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

                    >

 <!--IF I DELETE THE VIEWS IN THE TOOLBAR THE PROGRAMATICALLY SET TITLE COMES BACK-->

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#fff3f3f3"
                         android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text="Profile"
                        />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I've seen others with the same problem but I couldn't find a solution.

If anyone could help me or show me some material that I could use to fix the problem myself I would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Toolbar` internally has a `TextView`, so if you call `setTitle` it sets the text to that `TextView`.

If you want to have a custom `TextView`, just give it an id, find it, and set text to it.

```
...
<TextView android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"/>
...
```

Then,

```
Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView title = (TextView) toolbarTop.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
title.setText("Title");
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for the delayed reply. But the problem is that when I add a TextView or even just a View the programatically added title I added using setTitle() disappears. It doesn't matter if I don't add text to the TextView simply adding another view to the Toolbar makes the setTitle() text disappear. Have you got a Textview in the Toolbar to co-exist perse whilst also being able to use setTitle() with the Toolbar when using a CollapsingToolbarLayout ? Thanks